# Where can I find people who support Bitcoin as a "Purely peer-to-peer form of electronic cash"?

Tags: currencies, cash

I think it would be great to have a group with the purpose to support Bitcoin as a currency. What would be the best way to organize it?

Answer (score 1):

We are everywhere. I suggest starting with Bitcoin Knots and contributing to other projects depending on your own abilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to talk with people who want to stay on a purely monetary network I invite you to look at people with the hashtag [#FixTheFilters](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23FixTheFilters&src=typed_query) on Twitter.